# How to store data in array python variables row wise when fetching data from oracle and then use each element individually?

Tags: python, oracle

When i am trying to print "MSF" only with array as row[0] it is actually printing "MSF" two times. I am guessing the whole column is getting stored in the array as row[0].
Please suggest how to access to the 1st element of 1st Row of 1st column store it into an array then proceed with the 2nd element of 2nd Row of 1st column and store it again in the same array but different index value of array?

My table name is nemis.fin_prof_header and it is like

```
   STATE     TOC      ID      NUMBER
    MSF   MSPROFMSV 465984  5926987700
    MSF   MSPROFMSV 465977  5926063400
```

My Code:-

```
import cx_Oracle
import shutil
import os
import logging
import time
import re
timestr = '_'+time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")    

conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'lsaxena2/Dec2*19k@ed03:1521/encdv03svc.uhc.com') 
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('select * from nemis.fin_prof_header where rownum<3') 
result = c.fetchall()
for row in result:
  print (row[0])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result variable, which is a return value of [fetchall()](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/cursor.html#Cursor.fetchall) would have a list of tuples holding the data of your select query.
By using for loop, you are iterating one tuple at a time and row[0] would be selecting the first value of that tuple (which is the first column of the record selected).

Since your select query returns two records, the loop would iterate twice and print the first column of each of those records which is MSG.

To get first row's first column you can make use of `result[0][0]`

Answer (score 0):

The reason it prints it twice is because your `for` loop has 2 rows, so it prints `row[0]` for each of them. If you just want to print the *first* row, you have to exit the loop early.

```
result = c.fetchall()
for row in result:
  print (row[0])
  break
```

Alternately, you not use a `for` loop at all, and just do:

```
result = c.fetchall()
print (result[0][0])
```

Comment: result[0][0] is printing the first letter which it encounter. i.e it is printing "M" for "MSF' 2 times.

Comment: Huh. I'd expect to see that from result[0][0][0] or row[0][0]. I'm not sure what's going on there. Edited my answer to be more clear.